# What is the closest thing to a full restart that I can do via the terminal?

Tags: terminal, macos, crash, adobe

I am having issues with Adobe Dreamweaver on my Mac running Yosemite.

I will be in the middle of saving a file to my server and it just locks up. Nothing will happen after that. I try and force quit the application and it closes fine. However, when I try and re-open it, it just bounces.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBgQj_4fcIA

I have to restart the Mac 4-5 times a day because of this.

Is there a way to "clear" whatever is happening on a restart through a terminal command?

Its bad enough it locks up like this but if I could quickly clear the application from memory or cache; it would save a lot of time restarting.

Comment: Did you try saving the file locally, to eliminate the server connection as a possible cause?

Comment: I did not, would be kinda of a pain as a lot of it is server side so I like to see the changes in real time. I get that apps crash, but not being able to open it without restarting is very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

You're using cs6 that uses Java 6 and Yosemite I believe is Java 8. You could try installing java 6 but it isn't supported and neither is DWcs6. Unfortunately that's the way of it. I don't know if you have a creative cloud account. They provide all updates. If not you could try the Java route or another FTP client. :/
Edit::
Correction. I forgot since o have to install Java for dev purposes. Yosemite doesn't come stock with it. BUT I found this. It may help. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US